# WARNING ITMS-90901: "Missing full-screen support for the latest iPad mini display

Tags: include, bundle

WARNING ITMS-90901: "Missing full-screen support for the latest iPad mini display. The “ExpoKitApp.app” bundle includes UIRequiresFullScreen=YES in the Info.plist or supports only a subset of UISupportedInterfaceOrientations, and is built with the 14.1 SDK. To take advantage of the full screen size, recompile with Xcode 13 and the SDK for iPadOS 15 or later."

Comment: When did you get this warning? After you uploaded your app to Appstore and they rejected it with this warning?

Answer (score 8):

We have two options here

1. UIRequiresFullScreen=YES to your app’s Info.plist in order to keep your app full screen during multitasking, you’ll need to recompile with Xcode 13 and the SDK for iPadOS 15
2. Don’t include this key in your Info.plist file if your app supports iPad multitasking and is capable of running alongside other apps. If this key is absent, or is present and set to NO, the system lets your app share the screen with other apps. Can work with Xcode 12.

Comment: Does App store let you release the new version which is compiled with Xcode 12.4 and has UIRequiresFullScreen=YES?

Comment: App Store will allow to release with a warning!!
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "XX" 4.5.0. Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

ITMS-90901: Missing full-screen support for the latest iPad mini display. The “KY Lottery.app” bundle includes UIRequiresFullScreen=YES in the Info.plist or supports only a subset of UISupportedInterfaceOrientations...

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect

Answer (score 4):

You've to recompile your code in XCode 13+

[image: New update]

and for further details please visit [Apple's News and Update](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=oefg5bhp)

Comment: Do we need to recompile with XCode 13 and resubmit?

Comment: Yes @RohitSingh you have to Recompile your code with XCode 13* and then after your App is ready to Run in iPad mini fullScreen support

Comment: My app is built on Xcode 12 and is in App store. What happens when a iPad mini user opens my app. Will my app crash ? (I have set Requires Full screen = True in info.plist)

Comment: @RohithSingh, App will not crash but it will not full screen during multitasking in iPad Mini

Comment: @RohitSingh App will not crash but it will not full screen during multitasking in iPad Mini(2)

Answer (score 3):

i had the same issue, i sorted by upgrading to latest expo sdk and including this in the app.json `expo.ios.infoPlist {"UIRequiresFullScreen": true}`

Answer (score 0):

I was completely upgrading my macOS(12.2) and Xcode. Currently, no warning message showing.

Comment: Removing UIRequiresFullScreen should not be an ideal solution. What if the requirement is  to enforce full screen in an app all the time.

Comment: Hai, I was completely upgrading my macOS(12.2) and Xcode. Currently no warning message showing. So, I think this is the only solution.

Answer (score -1):

As the message says, recompile with Xcode 13.

Comment: Not useful. For example for me, Im building through expo and already have xcode 13 but error still the same.